# After "shutdown now" the system hangs with error "INFO: task S30kilprocs:xxxx blocked for more than 120 seconds."

Tags: shutdown

I wanted to shutdown immediately from root. After entering `shutdown now` I got this error.

```
INFO: task S30kilprocs:xxxx blocked for more than 120 seconds.
```

[image]